# Rename class object name within class itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.name = username

    def _chusername(self, new_name):
        old = self.name
        self.name=new_name

foo = User('foo')
foo._chusername('bar')
```

All that works. But I want the method `_chusername` also to change the name of the variable `foo` itself. So that `foo` as object doesn't exist anymore, but there was created a new object `bar` with the same attributes:

```
bar.name
'bar'
```

Therefore I need to address the name of the variable I assigned to the object within the class itself. Is that even possible? Is there a way my limited knowledge doesn't include?

Comment: You cannot do this, because there can be *many* references to your object, and they don't all have names either (think lists, sets and tuples).

Comment: `user._chusername(raw_input('Your username? ')); print ???.name`

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `foo` is just a name pointing to the `User` instance object. `bar = foo` would assign `bar` to the same object but doesn't create or destroy anything; neither does reassigning `foo = None`. You could do `bar = foo._chusername('bar')` and have the method return a new instance.

Comment: Can you imagine how crazy it would be to debug code if stack frames changed the previous frame's variable names? (!!!)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not something you want to do. It is *possible* (with a lot of work) to change global names and attributes on custom objects, but it is not a good idea.

Take the following example:

```
foo = User('foo')
siteconfiguration.administrator = foo
users = [foo]

def process_users(users):
    for user in users:
        user._chusername('bar')

process_users(users)
```

Here we have 5 references to the `User('foo')` instance (*at least*): The global name `foo`; the `administrator` attribute on the `siteconfiguration` object; the reference at index `0` in `users`; the local name `user` in the `for` loop in `process_users`; and the fifth reference is the `self` local name in the `User._chusername()` method, that's a reference to the same object! The `user` local name only references the object briefly, but the reference does exist when `User._chusername()` is called.

Now tell me what names should be changed when `user._chusername()` is called?

I said at the start that global names can be changed; you'd have to access the `globals()` dictionary and find all keys that reference the same object as `self`, and do so for *all modules Python currently has imported*. You'd then have to search through all custom objects, everywhere, if there are references to that same object; otherwise you won't find `siteconfiguration.administrator` in the above example.

This is a daunting task. Combing through [garbage collector results](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) can help here, but you are then so far down the Python rabbit hole you should probably rethink why you were doing this in the first place.

Comment: This is a great example. Your example aside, it's possible to "modify" the original variable name in the OP's example without a lot of work, by simply inspecting the previous stack frame and modifying its `f_locals` dict, but that's preposterous.

Comment: @netcoder: `f_locals` is only a reflection of the actual locals *array*, and altering it won't actually set locals in that frame. But yes, that's preposterous even if it was possible.

Comment: I said the previous frame, e.g.: `sys._getframe(1).f_locals[new_name] = self` AFAIK, that should work.

Comment: As I call foo._chusername('bar'), I want the method of the class User to create a new object instance of the same class. As I would type in myself: bar = User('bar'). But it shall happen automatically

Comment: @netcoder: not if the caller frame is a function, no. That only works if the caller frame is at global scope, because then `f_locals` is the same object as `f_globals`. If `sys._getframe(1)` is a function, on the other hand, the `f_locals` attribute is **not** the actual locals array, just a dictionary built from the locals on demand.

Comment: @eryksun: there are ways to create a closure cell without going into the C API or using ctypes, but yes.

Comment: @eryksun: Yes, something like that. I did something like that a few months back to monkey-patch a nested function with closure, certainly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the name of the variable itself, but can assign the object to a new variable
Like so:

```
>>> foo = User('foo')
>>> foo._chusername('bar')

>>> bar = foo
>>> del foo # Deletes the original 'foo' object
>>> bar.name
bar
```

But I don't understand what exactly you want to do. There must be a better way to do it than
to try to change the 'variable name.'

Do explain